# Build Linux Kernel Module using Makefile with different pathname

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a Linux kernel module using the standard example Makefile specified in the [Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf).  If the Makefile is called `Makefile`, then everything works.  If I rename the Makefile to `Makefile.hello` or something else, then it fails as it cannot find the path `Makefile`.  I was wondering if there is a command or set of flags I can add to my Makefile to make this function properly.  I need to rename the Makefile as I am calling it from CMake.  Cmake creates its own Makefiles and will commonly overwrite what I already have.

I replaced my kernel module code with the hello world example and replicated the problem.  I know its the makefile.

hello world example `hello.c`

```
/*
 * hello−1.c − The simplest kernel module.
 */
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
    /*
     * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
     */
    return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += hello.o

ifeq (,$(KDIR))
    KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
endif

PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) $(KCONFIG) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

If makefile is called `Makefile`. (Successfully builds)

```
$> make -f Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build M=/home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test/hello.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test/hello.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test/hello.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic'
```

Make output if makefile is called `Makefile.hello`  (Fails to build)

```
$> make -f Makefile.hello
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build M=/home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:1396: recipe for target '_module_/home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/msmith/Desktop/kernel-test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic'
Makefile.hello:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried adding the -f to the internal MAKE parameters, however that just caused more issues.

Comment: I doubt you can easily create a module with CMake. Kernel uses it's own build system called KBuild. https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-November/017320.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all Kbuild-related logic into the file `Kbuild`. Kernel's build system checks file with this name first, so it won't look into `Makefile`, created by CMake. This feature is documented in [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).

I use exactly this approach in my CMake projects, related with Linux kernel.

Comment: That solved it.  Thank you for your help.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Open script/Makefile.build into kernel tree:

```
 41 # The filename Kbuild has precedence over Makefile  
 42 kbuild-dir := $(if $(filter /%,$(src)),$(src),$(srctree)/$(src))  
 43 kbuild-file := $(if $(wildcard $(kbuild-dir)/Kbuild),$(kbuild-dir)/Kbuild,$(kbuild-dir)/Makefile)  
 44 include $(kbuild-file)
```

This part of code (43-44) include Makefile with name 'Makefile'.

Answer (score -1):

---

The default Makefile. Name = Makefile ... and Makefile-hello, or Makefile.hello.

```
obj-m    := hello.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

$ `make` : OK

$ `make -f Makefile-hello` OK

$ `make -f Makefile.hello` Also OK.

Your Makefile : $ `make -f Makefile.msmith` OK, no errors.

---